# PHP Help with Inheritance

Tags: php, oop

Consider, Base class A and derived class B.

Both interact with database. Class A uses table A and Class B (which is derived from A) also uses table B.

If I create an object of Class B and later at some stage in some file I access the same object by Class A and delete it then it deletes its instance in Table A but a part of its data is left in Table B (which is left with no parent). How to tackle this problem without defining Class A as abstract, as it has its own existence?

Thanks!
Sanket

Comment: A concrete example would help. Do you mean you have `Employee { id, name }` and `Manager extends Employee { officeNum }`, and you delete an `Employee` that should have been a `Manager`, leaving an "occupied" office with no occupant? I'd add a `type` column to the `employees` table so you can detect that managers must use `Manager` objects

Comment: `references table_A on delete cascade`? I don't see what this has to do with PHP, all you're asking is that some data in table B be deleted when the corresponding data in table A is deleted. Of course, a properly abstracted ORM system would never return an object of class A for an entity that's specialized to class B.

Answer (score 1):

Your best approach would probably be to utilise your database backend's foreign key support if it has it.  Assuming table A represents an object of class A, and table B holds the additional state that an object of class B needs, then that means that all A and B objects have entries in the A table, but only B objects have entries in both the A and B tables.

If an entry in the A table and an entry in the B table relate to state for the same B object, then you should define a foreign key in the B table that references the ID of the corresponding row in the A table.  Now if you attempt to delete a row from A, the database will know that the row in A you're deleting has an associated row in B and can act accordingly.  It can either prevent the deletion of the data in A, also delete the corresponding row in B, or change the B row's foreign key value to reference some default value.  What precise action you take will depend on what you're trying to achieve.

If your database does not support foreign keys (MySQL when working with the myISAM engine, for example) then things become a lot more complicated.  There are possibly ways of doing it in your PHP code, but all the ones I can think of off the top of my head require your base class to know details about the implementation of your derived classes, which is a huge no no in object oriented design.

You should also be asking yourself, why are you initializing a base class object with data that represents a derived class object?  Is this actually necessary for your design?  I've personally not run across a situation where this has been necessary, because a derived class implicitly always has all the functionality of the base class it derives from.

Comment: The base class does not need knowledge of the derived class when doing this in PHP. When you use an event framework or some other Observer implementation, the derived class can register pre/post save and delete callbacks to implement this functionality.

Answer (score -1):

I searched and finally found a workaround for this using "get_called_class()" PHP 5 function.

And in my views, this is the best way to do it.

In the Base class table, add a "class_type" column and while adding data add the the name of the class which added the row by "get_called_class()". Now, whenever any derived class calls this, the name of the class is added to the database.

When deleting the rows of DB, allow only that class to delete which created that row (by matching "class_type" and "get_called_class()")

Comment: Reason that I am not using "on delete cascade" in my DB is that, I may have files associated with classes and so I need a logic on the programming language level.